# Algorithm to Find Integer Solutions of Square Root

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, square-numbers

I have equations, when finally I have to find integer solutions (at least few) to something like this:
$y = \sqrt{ax^2 + bx + c}$
where b and c can be huge (30 - 40 decimal digits, maybe more, not sure now). Is there any way to speedup process, making algorithm effective (apart of brute force search)?
Edit: y is a variable too

Comment: Are these all integers, including $x$?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

from $y^2 = a x^2 + b x + c,$ as long as $a$ is positive but not a square, we get $$4ay^2 = 4 a^2 x^2 + 4abx + 4ac= 4 a^2 x^2 + 4 a b x + b^2 -(b^2 - 4ac),$$
$$ 4 a y^2 = (2ax+b)^2 - (b^2 - 4ac), $$
$$ (2ax + b)^2 - 4 a y^2 = b^2 - 4ac, $$
$$ w^2 - 4 a y^2 = n,  $$
where $n = b^2 - 4 a c.$
There are two ways that this might be tractable. In one case, if $|n|$ is really small, then we can find $(w,y)$ pairs by methods that are equivalent to continued fractions. The other extreme is when $|n| = p$ is prime and Legendre symbol $(a|p) = 1.$

The general name here is Pell equations. With large numbers, there is no guarantee that solutions can be found.

Comment: Thanks for that, so it looks, that in general case complexity could be huge...

Comment: @TomaszMadry yes. Suggest you learn how to investigate your problem when $a, |b|, |c| < 100.$ You don't get very far if you don't work out how to do small numbers. Start with $u^2 - n v^2 = 1,$ for positive $n$ not a square.

Comment: So is there some value for an equation that can be used to find all the solutions for certain values of a, b, and c?  Because I have found such equations, but I have not yet figured out the parameters of these equations relate directly to a, b, and c

Comment: @Michael  I think you also left a comment at one of my other answers,  where it seemed that what you wanted involved the square of the automorphism matrix. It had trace $6,$  its square had trace $34$

Comment: @WillJagy Ah, thanks.  It seems like {6,-1} and {-34,1} show up a *lot* for some reason...